# Why $H_t = \left \{ (s,f) \in [0, \infty) \times C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}) : s \leq t \textrm{ and } f(t-s) \le 0\right \}$ is measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, stochastic-analysis

My book of stochastic analysis, in a proof, says:

> The subset $H_t$ is measurable in $[0, \infty) \times C$, because $(s,f) \rightarrow f(t-s)$ is continuos in $[0,t] \times C$

$C$ is the space of continuos functions $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ and $H_t$ is $\left \{ (s,f) \in [0, \infty) \times C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}) : s \leq t \textrm{ and } f(t-s) \le 0\right \}$.

I'm convinced this is so, but I can not prove it. 
The result is valid only in $[0,t] \times C$ or it is valid in $[0, \infty) \times C$ if I remove the hypothesis $s \leq t$ and extend $f \in C$ to $f(x) = 0 \textrm{ if }x > t$?

Comment: $C[0,\infty)$ endowed with which $\sigma$-algebra....?

Comment: @saz Yes, $C[0,\infty)$ is measurable with $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{ f \in C | f(t_1) \in A_1, ... , f(t_k) \in A_k \}$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A_i \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Maybe I have solved: the function of the problem is in $\{f \in C | f(t-s) \in A \}$, where $A$ is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 0 \} \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. So $\{f \in C | f(t-s) \in A \} \in \sigma(C)$. 
It can be right?